# Ubuntu phone availability

Tags: phone

Does anyone have a detailed plan that shows the current availability of **Ubuntu Phone BQ Aquaris** to European countries?

Comment: Yep! Here: http://www.bq.com/gb/ubuntu.html  They just can't *make* them fast enough.  They're selling out in 5 minutes...

Comment: I was wondering if it will be available on physical stores.

Comment: @MarvinMicek there is currently nothing released about that. 2 things we know: 1. BQ is doing flash sales. 2. Next will be Meizu releasing up to 3 different phones but they are a Chinese company (so might focus on China).

Answer (score 1):

It is available at various 'flash sales' at a price of €169.90 . The last sale was on for a limited time on the 11th of Feburary, they may be another some time soon.

You can find out more here:

- https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/02/06/bqs-new-aquaris-e4-5-ubuntu-edition-the-smartphone-that-puts-content-and-services-at-your-fingertips/
- http://www.bq.com/gb/ubuntu.html

I think it is only available from BQ.com:

> 9th February 2015, London and Madrid: The world’s first Ubuntu phone – the Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition – will be available across Europe from BQ.com through a series of Flash Sales over the coming weeks
>   
>  .... 
>   Operators such as 3 Sweden, amena.com in Spain, giffgaff in the UK and Portugal Telecom are offering SIM bundles at purchase, exclusively from the BQ website, for buyers in those regions.

Comment: I was wondering about the availability on physical stores.